# htmlspecialchars only works in some environments

Tags: php, character-encoding, html-entities

i'm testing the exact same functionality in two different environments, one is a local development environment, and the other is a staging server. they have the exact same code.

when I do a `curl` request to each endpoint containing the functionality, I get two different results:

Local (php 5.4)

```
//this was the desired output
&lt;p&gt;&lt;span&gt;Awesome water shooting power&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

Staging (php 5.3)

```
//none of the html chars are changed.
<p><span>Awesome water shooting power</span></p>
```

the actual string of text is being run through `htmlspecialchars` in the following way:

```
htmlspecialchars( $req->get('description') )
```

Should I be specifically using all of the other arguments in this `htmlspecialchars` method in order to make it behave the same way in any environment? or is there something at the php.ini level that could be happening?

Comment: do you have the same versions of php at local and stage server, do you have any kind of proxy between them? Can you post whole code which downloads and outputs this string?

Comment: good question, @IlyaBursov, yes, they are different versions. local is 5.4.x, staging is 5.3.x. no proxying is happening.

Comment: Do you see the results through a terminal or how do you output it ?

Comment: i'm running curl in a terminal, and viewing its output there as well.

Comment: so, basically you want to say that `curl http://localhost/page.php` and `curl http://remothost/page.php` returns different results? If files are really the same - it is impossible

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the version of php http://3v4l.org/QsW7A

Comment: i just found this in the `htmlspecialchars` documentation: "[Argument 3] Defines encoding used in conversion. If omitted, the default value for this argument is ISO-8859-1 in versions of PHP prior to 5.4.0, and UTF-8 from PHP 5.4.0 onwards."

Comment: that was it. by not setting the args manaually, the defaults are different between 5.3 and 5.4. setting them explicitly caused the functions to evaluate to the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the php documentation for `htmlspecialchars`:

> **Encoding:** Defines encoding used in conversion. If omitted, the default value for this argument is ISO-8859-1 in versions of PHP prior
>   to 5.4.0, and UTF-8 from PHP 5.4.0 onwards.

so, based on that, I tried setting the fields explicitly, so they would not default to different things silently.

```
htmlspecialchars( $string , ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8' );
```

now the output is the same between the two different environments.